# Trying to access data returned from php in an ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call:

```
setStatusToActive: function(item){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Yii/trackstar/index.php?r=contentManagement/sidebars/SetWidgetStatusActive/',
                data: {'sid': <?php echo $this->_sidebarId->id ?>, 'widget_type': item.data('type'), 'position': item.data('position')},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    item.data('id', data);
                }
            });
        },
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to get the returned value from the php function that is called on the screen/log.

```
public function actionSetWidgetStatusActive(){
      ...

    return $widgetsUsed->id;
}
```

After this I want to use the returned number to set the data attribute from an item.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The only question I got is how I can get the returned php in the console or on the screen throughout javascript (as said in the title).

Comment: Why the negative hits? Remarkable..

Comment: i'm not sure if i have understand what is your goal, your question not clear, for me at less

Comment: Dunno why the downvotes? I upvoted to try even it out! Don't return the value, simply echo it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this: `echo json_encode($widgetsUsed->id);` and remove the `return` function.

Now if you check your console in Firebug, you will be able to see the result of your function. TO display properly in jQuery, you must use jQuery.parseJSON().

Comment: @SjaakRusma - If it works great, you should thank the user by upvoting their answer.